# Political system to automatically vote system for optimal life for everyone

Tags: political-theory, political-system, technology

﻿ What would a political system where you could cast a percentage to each party and have that percentage count as the amount of influence you would want that party to have in politics according to how safe your life would be if it were to win.﻿

And, would such a system be fair. Cause one person may cast some percentages, another one others, and a robot could easily determine the optimal percentages for each person, that that person could automatically use as their vote.﻿

But, then, if these percentages represented safety, how works you combine them to yield the perfect vote (of the system, to government).﻿ Thanks.﻿

Comment: "a robot could easily determine the optimal percentages for each person": ***citation needed***. How on earth would you calculate how "safe" a given person would be  under the rule of a given political party without automatically predicting how truthful the party is being, how the party will respond to future developments, and what those future developments actually will be! (Not to mention the behaviour of the individual and everyone else in society, and how that behaviour changes under different kinds of rule)

Comment: In politics often you need to come to some kind of consensus. How exactly is this achieved here? Like for example when some people want to increase taxes and others want to decrease them. Who does decide? The robot? And why? Life is safe probably equally within high or low taxes (within boundaries). What would you regard as optimal then?

Comment: A robot can easily do this? I think you should look up Isaac Asimov three laws of robotics and see all the ways that it can go wrong if things are done in the name or protection.

Comment: Few people who voted in 2019 UK General Election even slightly considered readiness for global pandemic as a criterion when choosing who to vote for. Possibly a robot would be better able to weigh risks and account (a little bit) for the finite possibility of very bad things happening where we know they are possible but don't know when, but it will rapidly be out of date.

Comment: What defines "safe"? Elimination of physical violence, lowered threat of foreign invasion, enhanced health care, reduced food poverty, or some combination of these and other factors? Who decides on the scaling weight of each factor into the total?

Comment: What does "according to how safe your life would be if it were to win" mean?

Answer (score 7):

As a system, this is a non-starter.

What you initially propose is a score based system (eg you might vote 40% conservative, 30% liberal, 25% socialist and 5% communist)  You don't say how multiple votes would be combined - but I suppose you imagine some sort of averaging. These systems are prone to dishonest voting.  The person above would know that their vote would be averaged, and it would be in their interest to vote "100% conservative 0% everyone else",

You then say that people vote "according to how safe your life would be".  But it is not possible to decide the criteria on how people vote.  If I want to vote for a party that will make me less safe, but richer.  I can do that.  How would you know, unless you can read my mind.

You then propose "a robot" to determine the optimal percentages.  This is simply impossible. Robots don't have this capacity. If there were a way for a robot to decide what was best. And everybody agreed it was always right, there would be no need for politics!

And even if there was such a robot, it wouldn't help.  Suppose my optimal vote was as above, but your optimal vote was "10% Conservative, 90% communist"  There is no way that we can both get the result we want, and averaging simply means we both lose.

Even something as simple as "influence" is very hard to control.  For example in a Parliament, if one party has 51% of the seats, and the other has 49%, that does not mean that the party with 51% has 51% of the "influence".  They have 100%.

So for all sorts of reasons. This is not a workable system for choosing a government.

Answer (score -1):

It's not hard to imagine a delegated voting system in XXI century. This way, you choose another person you trust to vote for you on a range on issues.

Once that system is up and running, a move to a more direct democracy is possible, such as a static parliament replaced with an open set of opinions holders, each of which holds a variable number of citizen's votes delegated to them.

Delegation to a person is arguably superior since you can always have a person following an algorithm but algorithm without a person can be gamed.

Comment: But how is it related to the question? What problem does it solve and why?

Comment: It solves the problem where you are give two dudes to vote for, to parliament or head of state, and both are awful